# CLI cursor is overlapping the string printed to the console?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

```
from time import sleep

for i in range(7200, -1 , -1):
    print(f"{i}", end="\r")
    sleep(1)
```

When I run the above python script, it counts down and replaces the old number with the current number so it all stays on the same line.  However, per the below image, the CLI cursor (not sure if that's what it's called, I'm still fairly new to programming) overlaps the numbers.  I'm not quite sure how to rectify this so the cursor doesn't do that.  I'd prefer it to go to the next line, but if that isn't possible then go to the end of the printed number.

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg5jz.png)

This happens both in VS Code and the mac terminal.

I wasn't able to find anything regarding this, but that's probably because I just don't know what terms to exactly use. I tried putting \r and \n in different places, but most of my attempts just kept printing to a new line.

Comment: You could make the output look a bit nicer by putting a space in front of the number, so the cursor will pause there instead of over a digit.  If you really want it after the number, you need to output the carriage return *first*, and output nothing after the number: `print(f"\r{i}", end="")` for example.

Comment: @jasonharper thank you so much!! it looks a lot nicer now with the cursor not overlapping any of the numbers.  would there be a way to have the cursor be below the number as it counts down?  if not, this will do, but definitely something i'm interested in

Comment: Moving the cursor up a line (to rewrite it) is less supported that using carriage return to move to the start of the current line.  Historically, there was no one standard way to do this - although these days, any terminal program that supports cursor control at all will use some variant of ANSI escape sequences, so you can try printing `"\033[A"` to move up a line, or possibly `"\033[F"` to move to the start of the previous line.

Comment: @jasonharper this is exactly what i was looking for!  after some messing around with it, i came up with this `print(f'\033[F{j}')`.  however to get it to work, i had to print an empty string prior to running the loop.  i can't link images, but this allows for the countdown to appear on the line above where the cursor is, which was purely just an aesthetic choice for me.  thanks again!